# Lib to display OpenGL video in PyQt?

Tags: qt, opengl, pyqt

I know that a classic way of displaying OpenGL elements inside (Py)**Qt** is to override the `QGLWidget.paint()` method to make direct OpenGL calls.
However, does anyone know of a **lib I could use to avoid making direct calls to OpenGL?** Something that would, for example, load an image or video frame to a textured triangle strip in a single call? Or any kind of OpenGl video lib that I could integrate with PyQt?

My final goal is to display OpenGL video inside a PyQt window.

Comment: @genpfault Is there a place on Stackexchange where I could ask that kind of question?

Comment: [Software Recommendations](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) is more appropriate.

Comment: See also http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/9310

Comment: Shames on the dude who made this "-1"! :)

Comment: Were you able to find the solution? I have the same problem

Comment: @kinglaz the closest would be pyglet. So no, i finally ended up doing it directly from pyopengl

Comment: That's unfortunate! Thanks